# modular forms and line bundle

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $\Gamma \leq SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ be a congruence subgroup, $X$ the corresponding compact modular curve. I often see the statement (for example, in many posts here on SE) that modular forms (of weight $k$) $M_k(\Gamma)$ can be interpreted as being global sections of a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$. However I am getting confused between two meanings of this:

1. For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a line bundle $\mathcal{L}_k$ such that $M_k = H^0(X,\mathcal{L}_k)$
2. There exists a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ such that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $M_k = H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes k})$

Clearly 2 implies 1. But when are these statements true? Is 1 always true, for instance? Or do we need further conditions on $\Gamma$, concerning for example, elliptic elements and irregular cusps?

I've seen it also stated in some places (for example, [Eyal Goren's lectures](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/PAPERSpublic/SMS.pdf), also [Milne's notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/MF110.pdf) construct the line bundle assuming free action of $\Gamma$) that the existence of a line bundle in the sense of 1 requires $\Gamma$ not to have elliptic elements or irregular cusps. 
But in other places I just see the assertion that this line bundle exists, with no conditions on $\Gamma$. Some people use the canonical bundle on $X$ and assert that this gives the modular forms as global sections in the sense of 2. But for some reason I find it hard to believe that this is always true; in any case, I couldn't find any clear reference about it.

I would greatly appreciate any help to clear away my confusion. Most references I was able to find about this are very sketchy and confusing. Does anyone know a good place to look it up?

Answer (score 5):

The statements are both true, but not because they are equivalent. The line bundle $L$ you consider is probably the dualizing sheaf $\omega$ (or just canonical sheaf or just sheaf of relative differentials depending on your base scheme). Then modular forms of weight $k$ correspond to global sections of $\omega$.

Maybe Peter Bruin's thesis could help here.

See http://user.math.uzh.ch/bruin/thesis.pdf

Especially

Equation I.2.1 (The language is a bit heavy in this section but it becomes more down to earth later).

page 76 might also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. The line bundle considered in the equation you pointed to is a line bundle on a moduli stack, and not on a scheme. This stack is representable for level structure $\Gamma_1(n)$, $n\geq 5$ (says so on page 8). I know that $\Gamma_1(n)$ has no elliptic points. Does that have to do maybe with whether this line bundle can be moved to the modular curve $H^*/\Gamma$ (which is a Riemann surface)?

Comment: @Hamburger: Are you sure? I agree that statement (1) is true for any $\Gamma$, but I am sure that statement (2) is false -- if it were true, then by Riemann-Roch the dimension of $M_k$ would be a linear function of $k$ for $k \gg 0$, which is false for general $\Gamma$.

Comment: @David. Hmm, I think I was confused. You're right that statement 2 is false in this generality.

Comment: A necessary condition for $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes k}$ to descend to $\Gamma$ is that $k$ should kill the torsion in $\Gamma$, and that $k$ should also be even if $\Gamma$ has irregular cusps. I think this condition is also sufficient but I'm not sure.

Comment: @David: Thanks, do you mean for $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes k}$ to descend from the stack to the modular curve? Would you happen to have any reference explaining this condition further?

Comment: When I said "descend", I meant: choose some auxilliary level structure, say full $\Gamma(N)$ level structure for some $N \gg 0$, and consider $X(\Gamma \cap \Gamma(N))$; this certainly has a sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ on it, and also there is a natural Galois cover $X(\Gamma \cap \Gamma(N)) \to X(\Gamma)$ and one can ask if $\mathcal{L}$ descends. This is an alternative and more explicit approach that avoids using stacks.

Comment: That's great, thanks.